# Eclipse showing bogus errors

Tags: eclipse

Since I updated to Eclipse Juno, the error detection seems to be off and not be able to keep up with me also. I opened Eclipse today and saw this error, which is obviously bogus:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/error1ae.png/

Any ideas on how to fix Eclipse or why it's happening? (I know I can just delete the error in the problems tab, but I don't want this to happen in the first place...)

Comment: Oof. Please using the SO image hosting instead of that horribly spammy site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the problems views "type" column, you will probably find "Android Lint" being the source, although this looks like a Java problem. Use the "Clear" button of the Android Lint view to get rid of the error message.

Until they get that issue fixed in the ADT, it may make sense to disable automatic lint checking.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I ignored everything but API level checking.